# rewrite plugin not working while upgrading spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to upgrade my spring boot project from 2.7.6 to spring boot 3.2

I am using below plugin

```
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.25.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <activeRecipes>
                    <recipe>
                        org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot3.UpgradeSpringBoot_3_2</recipe>
                </activeRecipes>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
                    <artifactId>rewrite-spring</artifactId>
                    <version>5.7.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

As a command I am using mvn rewrite:run but nothing is getting update in my project.

Getting below logs in my console

```
   [INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ springboot-crud-jpa ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< rewrite:5.25.0:run (default-cli) < process-test-classes @ springboot-crud-jpa <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- rewrite:5.25.0:run (default-cli) @ springboot-crud-jpa ---
[INFO] Using active recipe(s) [org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot3.UpgradeSpringBoot_3_2]
[INFO] Using active styles(s) []
[INFO] Validating active recipes...
[INFO] Project [springboot-crud-jpa] Resolving Poms...
[INFO] Project [springboot-crud-jpa] Parsing source files
[INFO] Running recipe(s)...
```

Am I missing anything here?

Below is my complete pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-crud-jpa</name>
    <description>spring boot crud operations example with JPA</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.25.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <activeRecipes>
                        <recipe>
                            org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot3.UpgradeSpringBoot_3_2</recipe>
                    </activeRecipes>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
                        <artifactId>rewrite-spring</artifactId>
                        <version>5.7.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: [INFO] Running recipe(s)... After this line nothing is happening. Can someone please suggest am I missing anything here